# Call django staticfiles tag from inside a view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'd like to call the staticfiles `static` tag inside my view, or its equivalent. How can I do that?

What I've tried: nothing so far.

What I've found: a bunch of questions asking how to call a function inside a template, which is the exact opposite of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
staticfiles_storage.url(same_as_templatetag_argument)
```